# Sign-in button prompts for Credentials and successfully authenticates but, doesn't log-in the user

Tags: oauth, botframework, microsoft-teams

## Ms Teams Chat Bot : MS Teams OAuth Authentication Sign-in button prompts for Credentials and successfully authenticates but, doesn't log-in the user

---

### Using MS Teams: Validation Code Text Box Popup Doesn't Show up:

> > *In MS Teams The Sign-in button works to show the login prompt, the authentication is successful but then, The Validation code Text Box doesn't show up and the further Bot code is not executed. When I re-type the utterance "Hi" it, shows the Sign-in button again.*

### Using Azure Webchat & MS Bot Emulator: Validation Code Text Box Popup shows Up:

> > In Azure Webchat, on clicking the Sign-in button, it shows the login prompt-> on successful authentication, it brings up the numeric Validation Code textbox. On pasting this Validation code in the chat window, the further chatbot code gets executed and am able to use the chatbot well.

**Sign in oAuth Card Comes up in MS Teams, Azure Web Chat and Bot Emulator**

[image]

**Login Prompt Comes up in MS Teams , Azure Web Chat and Bot Emulator**

[image]

**Validation Code TextBox, *Doesn't Show* in MS Teams *but, It is visible* in Azure Web Chat and Bot Emulator**

### [image]

### Is it possible?

*Is it possible that some configuration in MS Teams is blocking the Numeric Validation Code Text box to show up?*

### More Information

- Manifest has Valid domains set as:  **token.botframework.com**
- Am using My **Mobile phone hotspot** to connect to the internet so,
  **NO Proxy** in between

Comment: Node.js or C#? Could you share some of your code. How are you handling the Invoke Activity?

Comment: Am using the C# based MS BotFramework V4  .  <br/>  **Didn't understand your question about the Invoke Activity part.**  <br> -Thanks

Comment: You need to have TeamsActivityHandler to handle this inside Teams. Could you please try this [sample for authentication](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth)?

Comment: Hi Gousia... it worked somehow I missed inheriting from this class when retrofitting oAuth Code to the existing ChatBot but, am facing another issue i.e. when I click the Submit Button on another Adaptive Card, the MainDialog.BeginDialogAsync(,object options,...,..) is receiving Options parameter as Null , due to which am unable to extract the user response  from the Adaptive Card. Any Sggestion?

Comment: Have posted another question to solve the Exception coming up after implementing the OAuth related changes. Although the OAuth is now working in MS Teams but, the Adaptive Card Submit clicks have stopped getting the user-provided values .  Here is the link to the new Question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59678612/12178176)